# "open windows powershell" not working from windows 10 file explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, powershell

Not sure what happened, but when I open windows 10 file explorer and goto the menu:

```
File->Open Windows PowerShell->Open Windows Powershell
```

Then it doesn't do anything.   Meaning it doesn't open a powershell window.  I just does nothing.

Strangely, it still works if I goto:

```
File->Open Wndows PowerShell->Open Windows Powershell as administrator
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem?  Because it very handy to open
powershell window in the current file explorer directory:

Comment: This is a Windows Explorer issue, not a PS specific thing. I'd suggest using System Restore a go back to a time where it was working. Now, using a restore will impact your current working state, so, you need to evaluate if it is worth that.

Comment: Does the problem exist regardless of the current directory Explorer has open? Are you able to open up Powershell from Run (`Win`+`R`, type "powershell", click OK)?

Comment: it lauches ok from start menu...  just doen't launch from "file explorer" short cut as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Check `C:\Users` for files without extensions. If present, delete them or move them somewhere else.

---

In my case, an extensionless log file was created in `C:\Users` by **Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) - 14.34.31931** when it was installed by the Visual Studio 2022 installer. Apparently, this vcredist installer didn't properly support spaces in the path to the installer's log file.  The path it tries to use is somewhere in %USERPROFILE%, so if you have a space in your username (like I did) then instead of using `C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\whatever-they-actually-wanted.log` it will use `C:\Users\Firstname` as the log file. No file extension, just `Filename`.

Somehow this screws up File Explorer when it tries to load Windows PowerShell. In my case, sometimes, depending on which directory I had open in File Explorer, trying to open Windows PowerShell with the File menu would give me a dialog window asking which program I'd like to use to open an unspecified file.  I chose Notepad, which produced the installer's logfile, which I read to figure out what was going on.

Here's an excerpt of the logfile that has the important details highlighted.

> [3B74:44BC][2022-11-13T18:58:52]i001: Burn v3.10.4.4718, Windows v10.0
> (Build 19045: Service Pack 0), path:
> C:\Windows\Temp{99D8376B-C723-495D-B87B-D82588989251}.cr\**VC_redist.x64.exe**
> [3B74:44BC][2022-11-13T18:58:52]i009: Command Line:
> '-burn.clean.room=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\**VisualStudio**\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.34.31931,chip=x64\VC_redist.x64.exe
> -burn.filehandle.attached=684 -burn.filehandle.self=788 /q /norestart /log C:\Users\Firstname
> Lastname\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20221113185346_963_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest.log'
> [3B74:44BC][2022-11-13T18:58:52]i000: Setting string variable
> 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value
> 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.34.31931,chip=x64\VC_redist.x64.exe'
> [3B74:44BC][2022-11-13T18:58:52]i000: Setting string variable
> 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value
> 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.34.31931,chip=x64'
> [3B74:44BC][2022-11-13T18:58:52]i000: **Setting string variable
> 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\Firstname'**
> [3B74:44BC][2022-11-13T18:58:52]i000: Setting string variable
> 'WixBundleName' to value '**Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022
> Redistributable (x64) - 14.34.31931**'

Removing the logfile from `C:\Users\` solved the problem, and now I can open Windows PowerShell with File Explorer again - both with Administrator privileges and without.